# How to escape a string in python to use as an xpath key

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I got this key error in python

```
  KeyError: ("./note/[@player='Ba'g']",)
```

when using

```
  player = "Ba'g"
  xpathstring = "./note/[@player='{}']".format(player.replace("'","\'"))
  p = xmltree.find(xpathstring)
```

So I am wondering how to escape the string such that I can use as an xpath search string in an xmltree

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are passing the string `"./note/[@player='Ba'g']"` to the find function.

There seems to be no way to properly [escape single quotes in xpath](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit/issues/110).

However, you can switch from single to double quotes.
Try:

```
 xpathstring = "./note/[@player=\"{}\"]".format(player)
```

This is the suggested solution in the linked issue.

Comment: Ah thanx. It works but unfortunately my input contains also player with " so I guess I have to find another way to search through my xml document then using xpath.

Comment: def findPlayerNote(tree, player) :
    elemlist = tree.findall('note')
    for elem in elemlist:
        if (elem.get("player") == player) :
            return elem
    return None

Answer (score 0):

I propose this workaround (XPath 2.0) :

Assuming you have an element with an attribute which contains single and double quotation marks :

```
<div>
<note player="Ba&apos;g&quot;N Toast">foo</note>
</div>
```

To select this node with XPath and a fixed variable we can use something like :

```
import  re
player = '''Ba'g"N Toast'''
result = re.sub(r"(.+)", r"'\1'",player.replace("'","',codepoints-to-string(39),'").replace('"',"',codepoints-to-string(34),'"))
xpathstring = "//note[@player=concat({})]".format(result)
p = xmltree.find(xpathstring)
```

We replace `'` and `"` with their codepoints equivalents. The result will feed the `concat` function in the XPath expression.